# Safari ajax request intermittent blank status and response

Tags: ios, session, cookies, safari, frontend

recently I am trying to debug an issue where a few crucial requests gone blank and thus causing user to log out accidentally, this issue only happens in IOS not on any other browser,

so basically the network panel looks like this

```
Summary
URL: https://exampleURL.com
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator:  exampleURL.com:154:16986

Request
Accept: */*
Referer: https://exampleURL.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Response
No response headers
```

I was trying to capture those requests with Charles proxy, but there were no network requests at all, can anyone tell me what's could be next step for debugging in safari?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, if page is transitioning to the next page, all the ongoing requests will be terminated, this is a unsent Ajax request

In safari, an UNSENT ajax request will trigger error callback with $.ajax, if there is no checking on the error status code inside error callback, this may cause unexpected errors